# How is optimal Glide Path Altitude calculated?

Tags: visual-flight-rules, ppl

Good day,

On a PPL checkride quite a while ago I got asked "if you are 10 miles from the airport how high should you be for a 3 degree glideslope?" Can someone run me down on how to do the math to figure it out quickly?

Comment: The quick math would be the reverse of the calculation needed to calculate the number of miles needed to descend from one altitude to another. Take 10, subtract 2, divide by 3, then multiply by 1000. This gives you close to 2,700 feet.

Comment: Isn’t HEIGHT of aircraft more useful information on the glide path? Technically, if you’re asked to find ALTITUDE then you have to take QNH into account. The math will give you HEIGHT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just memorize the value 320 ft/nautical mile.

A 3 degree slope is a 19:1 gradient.  1 nautical mile is 6076 ft, divided by 19, = 319.8 ft.

Round up to 320 ft/mile which is close enough, and memorize that value, and multiply by the number of miles in your head as required, so 10 miles is easy; 3200 ft above the runway threshold.  Add to that the runway elevation and there's your target indicated altitude value.

If you're asked for an odd number like 7 miles, the quickest way to mentally work out 7 times 320, for me at least, is to to multiply hundreds first, then the tens after and sum them.  So, 300 x 7, for 2100, then multiply 20 x 7, or 140, and add 140 to 2100 to get 2240.  That type of mental math structure seems to work well when under pressure or with distractions.

For statute miles, the value is 280 ft/mile (actually 279, but close enough).

Answer (score 6):

While @JohnK’s answer is more accurate, the usual rule of thumb is 3nm/1000ft to determine when to start your descent. This “pilot math” is much easier and faster to do in your head, and the error is within the variation due to wind anyway.

In your case, the question is reversed, so 1000ft/3nm, or 333ft/1nm.

Comment: THIS is by far the best answer! I can do "three miles per thousand feet" far faster & more accurately than "miles x 320 feet". If a delta of 133' at 10 miles matters, then you're ***waaay*** beyond the realm of rules of thumb!

Comment: In a long descent yes, and I use that, but his question was related to determining height on a glideslope closer to the airport, which you could take to mean what is the height above threshold of an ILS 10 miles out, where a bit more precision would be useful.

Comment: @JohnK Reversing a simple rule I use on every flight will get me an answer faster and easier than getting out a calculator to do it your way. Sometimes speed matters more than precision.

Comment: @StephenS The question wasn't about rules of thumb for when to start an enroute descent.  The question was more direct, in effect, what is the height above threshold on a 3 deg GLIDESLOPE 10 miles out, inferring an ILS glideslope, and demanding a more precise number than the 60:1 rule for enroute descents gives.  If the OP just said what gives a ~ 3 deg angle on an enroute descent, I would have given your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. You can get your distance on a 3 degree glide by multiplying the altitude by distance. For example, if you want to know what your distance is at 3000 ft, just divide the altitude by 1000 and then multiply the number you get by 3. In this case (3 × 3) = 9 nm.

If you want to know what your altitude is at a certain distance then you can reverse the calculation. Divide the distance by 3. So, 10 nm is  (10 ÷ 3) = 3.3. Multiply this by 1000 which will give you an altitude of 3300 ft.

You can also use trigonometry. That is a triangle with a 3 degree angle with 10 nm as adjacent, we can find the opposite.

tan 3 = x/10

x = 10 tan 3

x = 0.524 nm.

You can then convert it to feet. The answer then becomes 3183 ft.

The first method I mentioned is a simple short cut that you can use in the aircraft (the most accurate method ofcourse is the trig).

It works from a simple Cessna to the largest jet. I still use the same calculation for the A320 and it works. But in jets we add about 10 nm to the answer for deceleration.